# Sort order slider // "For each" in TypoScript

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

I have a problem with my self made carousel slider. Unfortunately the order is random!

The pid for the slider elements are defined in TS constants:

`slider_site_ids = 1359,1348,1076,1067,1078,1117,1346,1349,1376`

But this order is not the one displayed on the page.

The slider itself is build like that:

```
lib.contentSlider = COA
lib.contentSlider {
  10 = CONTENT
  10 {
    table = tt_content
    select.where = colPos = 1
    select.languageField = sys_language_uid
    select.orderBy = sorting
    select.pidInList = {$slider_site_ids}
  }
  10.wrap = <div class="slider-img-cnt">|</div>

  20 = CONTENT
  20 {
    table = tt_content
    select.where = colPos = 10
    select.languageField = sys_language_uid
    select.pidInList = {$slider_site_ids}
  }
  20.wrap = <div class="content-left fl-left">|</div>

  30 = CONTENT
  30 {
    table = tt_content
    select.where = colPos = 20
    select.languageField = sys_language_uid
    select.pidInList = {$slider_site_ids}
  }
  30.wrap = <div class="content-right fl-right">|</div>

  40 = CONTENT
  40 {
    table = tt_content
    select.where = colPos = 30
    select.languageField = sys_language_uid
    select.pidInList = {$slider_site_ids}
  }
  40.wrap = <div class="slogan-box"><div class="first-line">|</div>

  50 = CONTENT
  50 {
    table = tt_content
    select.where = colPos = 40
    select.languageField = sys_language_uid
    select.pidInList = {$slider_site_ids}
  }
  50.wrap = <div class="second-line">|</div>

  60 = CONTENT
  60 {
    table = tt_content
    select.where = colPos = 50
    select.languageField = sys_language_uid
    select.pidInList = {$slider_site_ids}
  }
  60.wrap = <div class="third-line">|</div></div>  
}

lib.contentSlider.wrap = <article>|</article>
```

Is there a way to define the sort order? Maybe a for each loop will do the trick? Any ideas?

Comment: Side question: Why are you not encapsulating your `wrap` of 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 and 60 inside the bracets but write it outside as e.g. `60.wrap` ?

Comment: I'm pretty new in Typoscript so to me this is easier to read. Are there any consequences in functionality?

Comment: No, it wont affect the result, was just wondering if you intended as its only the "wrap" line outside every time.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use the [split function](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Split/Index.html) of typoscript.

EDIT: **Example**

```
20 = TEXT
20 {
    value = {$slider_site_ids}

    split {
        token = ,
        cObjNum = 1

        1.10 = CONTENT
        1.10 {
            table = tt_content
            select.where = colPos = 10
            select.languageField = sys_language_uid
            select.pidInList.current = 1
        }
    }
}
```